# A corollary of Brun's pure sieve from Opera de Cribro by Friedlander and Iwaniec

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory, twin-primes

I'm stuck on the one (if not many) step of the proof of Corollary 6.2 (page 58) from the book "Opera de Cribro" by Friedlander and Iwaniec.

The statement is a corrollary of Brun's pure sieve as follow:

> Suppose $|r_d|\leq g(d)d$ where $d\mid P(z)$. Then,
> $$|S(\mathcal{A},z)-XV(z)|\leq2V(z)X(\log X)^{-1}+X^\frac{3}{4},$$
> for $X\geq4$ and
> $$4\leq z\leq X^{1/c\log(V(z)^{-1}\log X)}.$$

It is proved in the book that
$$|S(\mathcal{A},z)-XV(z)|\leq\left(\frac{eG}{r}\right)^r(X+z^r)+e^r,$$
where
$$G=\sum_{p\mid P(z)}g(p)\leq-\log V(z).$$
It is clear that
$$z^r\leq X \quad \text{and} \quad e^r\leq X^\frac{1}{\log4}\leq X^\frac{3}{4}.$$
Thus, it remains to show that
$$\left(\frac{eG}{r}\right)^r\leq\frac{V(z)}{\log X}.$$
This is where I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm not providing definitions for everything here due to there are a lot. My hope is that people who read this is familiar with the notations of Friedlander and Iwaniec, or similar sieve notations. However, if neeeded, I can offer more explainations.